# Criticize my Inspection Route SQL Schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema, sql-server-express

New account but I've been lurking for years. I'm currently in the midst of developing a maintenance inspection software to replace an aging system my company utilizes. I have virtually no backend database experience but have done my best at putting together a basic design. Below I've included my table schema - I tried to practice the 3 normalization rules the best that I could. I am probably most concerned with the component_schedule table joining component, schedule, and inspection definitions. I am also concerned with the linking I have done around the table holding inspection responses - separate tables for text, numeric, and checklist type responses being linked to separate inspection definition subtables. I have a sneaking suspicion I have done something inefficient here.

Here's a basic overview of what I want to be able to do in the end. I've got the front end basically set up using powerapps.

Someone will be able to go out and perform a "route". The route will have multiple pieces of equipment associated with it and equipment items will each have multiple components. A single component will be able to have several different inspection types. Inspections will consist of list items (checked/unchecked), numeric items (gallons added, etc), and text responses (comments, problems, etc). An equipment's component will only be included in the route if it is scheduled to be completed in the current time period (today or this week depending on what the route schedule is - don't think I've defined a good table to track route schedules yet).

My hands are somewhat tied on the inspection definition/subcomponents as I'm importing a vast amount of data from an old database that needs to be compatible, but I am not confident that I've chosen a good way to relate inspection records to the inspection definitions/components themselves. Please critique me! If you've got any advice pointing me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it. If this is a terrible design feel free to let me know! This is really my only roadblock in moving forward right now and I don't want to build something on top of a poor database. This database is currently on MS SQL express but will eventually be moved to standard edition, hosted on AWS.

[schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i3ab.png)

Comment: @Carcigenicate A database schema is not code to review, maybe "Database administrators"?. Anyhow, it always boils down to: 1- Database normalization rules. 2- Remember some ORM have primary key limitations. 3- Always have in mind the client requirements.

Comment: My bad, wasn't sure even quite how to tag any of this. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: This is both too broad and opinion based. But one thing I would say is that you should run away from the idea of giving every table a column named ID. A column name should be consistent across the database, not change based on what table it is in. For example a RouteID is ALWAYS a RouteID. It isn't an ID in the Route table which suddenly gets a meaningful name in another table. Also, don't use the text datatype. It has been deprecated for well over a decade now in favor of varchar(max). But seriously, you don't need things like route name to be anywhere near that long.

Comment: @Sean Lange I totally disagree. To me column names are relative to the entity. I have a ton of "name" columns (as well as "id", "started_at", "status", etc.), for different tables that need one. Otherwise, your application code becomes really verbose with attributes like "personOrderPlacedTimestamp". You don't want that.

Comment: @TheImpaler LOL unless personOrderPlaceTimestamp is also a foreign key it would be fine. But a RouteID is always a RouteID, not an ID in the Route table. It drives me nuts when columns change names between tables.

Comment: @Sean Lange I guess I tend to look at it from the application coding perspective where the focus is to eliminate errors fast and make debug easy. I'm not saying you are wrong, just we may have different points of view. Anyway, this is kind of a dogmatic issue where positions are so disparate it's not easy to get an agreement on.

Comment: @TheImpaler I agree with that 100%. :)